# "park the pitch in the bay" meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

They are watching baseball and the dialogue goes:

-How's your favorite player doing?

-About to park this next pitch in the bay, I hope.

I need to translate this, what does he mean by "park this next pitch in the bay"?

It is from a series and two men are watching baseball and say this, there is no other context.

Comment: "They are watching baseball"    Who?   please be clear with your source.  Is this from a movie, a book, a textbook?  Something else.

Answer (score 1):

Park, baseball slang, "hit out of the park"

> (transitive, baseball) To hit a home run; to hit the ball out of the park.

In the bay, probably this comes from some coastal city next to a bay, so "hit a home run so far it lands in the sea."

Comment: More specifically, likely a San Fransisco Giants home game, where homeruns that land in the water is a known achievable occurrence.

Comment: My guess would be San Fransisco,  but I'll wait for a source from the OP

Comment: Thanks, I don't know where they are but I guess the meaning is just like you said, that it will land very far.